# Intermittent #1034 Type Coercion Failed AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have this very annoying intermittent problem that occurs every now and again in development only. I've never seen it happen in the published version of the swf.

```
  TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert flash.display::MovieClip@7737cf1 to PhotoInworldFl.
        at flash.display::Sprite/constructChildren()
        at flash.display::Sprite()
        at flash.display::MovieClip()
        at PhotoContainerFl()
```

There is a loop that builds the Photos. I've been through lots of other answers on Stack Overflow and have checked that PhotoContainerFl only contains movie clips.. no buttons or such like.

Often if I re-publish the swc before re-importing into Flash Builder, it goes away for a while, and then comes back.

The Flash Builder Debug window seems to show a few nulls in there, any idea what would cause that?
 [image: stack trace window]

Is there anything else I can try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are compiling against an asset swc file, it's caused by an ASC compiler bug that Adobe plan to fix soon. See this thread for details [Type Coercion failures with MovieClips in ASC 2.0](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1216937?start=0&tstart=0) .

Until the bug is fixed, the main thing that you can do is avoid having swc assets with both a linkage class set and a use count greater than zero.